# How to provide radio buttons as responses in chatbot I tried all the possible solutions but no go

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button, chatbot

```
def radio():
    def sel():
       selection = "You selected the option " + str(var.get())
       label.config(text = selection)


    var = IntVar()
    R1 = Radiobutton(base, text="Option 1", variable=var, value=1,
                      command=sel)
    R1.pack( anchor = W )

    R2 = Radiobutton(base, text="Option 2", variable=var, value=2,
                      command=sel)
    R2.pack( anchor = W )

    R3 = Radiobutton(base, text="Option 3", variable=var, value=3,
                      command=sel)
    R3.pack( anchor = W)

    label = Label(base)
    label.pack() 
    ChatLog.config(state=NORMAL)
    ChatLog.insert(END, "Bot: " + R1 + '\n\n')
    ChatLog.yview(END)`enter code here`



base = Tk()
base.title("POS Chatbot")
base.geometry("400x500")
base.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
#Create Chat window
ChatLog = Text(base, bd=0, bg="white", height="8", width="50", font="Arial",)
ChatLog.config(state=DISABLED)
ChatLog.config(foreground="#442265", font=("Verdana", 12 ))
#Bind scrollbar to Chat window
scrollbar = Scrollbar(base, command=ChatLog.yview, cursor="heart")
ChatLog['yscrollcommand'] = scrollbar.set
#Create Button to send message
base.bind('<Return>',call ) 
SendButton = Button(base, font=("Verdana",12,'bold'), text="Send", width="12", height=5,
                    bd=0, bg="#32de97", activebackground="#3c9d9b",fg='#ffffff',
                    command= send )
#Create the box to enter message
EntryBox = Text(base, bd=0, bg="white",width="29", height="5", font="Arial") #Place all components on the screen
scrollbar.place(x=376,y=6, height=386)
ChatLog.place(x=6,y=6, height=386, width=370)
EntryBox.place(x=128, y=401, height=90, width=265)
SendButton.place(x=6, y=401, height=90)
base.mainloop()
```

The radio buttons are appearing in the main window but not as a response. Please help me figure out what needs to be done to add the button type response in the chatbot. Below is my JSON file dataset that I'm using for this bot. Is there anything to change in the dataset for button type response. Please guide me through this problem

```
{
  "intents": [{
      "tag": "greeting",
      "patterns": ["Hi", "How are you", "Is anyone there?", "Hello", "Good day"],
      "responses": ["Hello, thanks for visiting", "Good to see you again", "Hi there, how can I help?"],
      "context_set": ""
    },
    {
      "tag": "thanks",
      "patterns": ["Thanks", "Thank you", "That's helpful"],
      "responses": ["Happy to help!", "Any time!", "My pleasure"]
    },
    {
      "tag": "bye",
      "patterns": ["bye", "good bye", "bubuye"],
      "responses": ["Have a nice day!", "Bye! I helped you", "Bye! Eager to see you again"]
    },
    {
      "tag": "pinpad",
      "patterns": ["I am having issue with the pinpad", "pinpad is not working", "PED is not working", "PP is not working", "issue with PED", "Card transactions are not going on", "pin pad is having issue"],
      "responses": ["please enter the till mac id the pinpad is connected with"]
    },
    {
      "tag": "scale",
      "patterns": ["I am having issue with the scale", "scale is not working", "weigh scale is not working", "weigh check is not working", "issue with scale", "weigh scale is not going on"],
      "responses": ["please enter the till mac id the scale is connected with"]
    },
    {
      "tag": "tasks",
      "patterns": ["What can you do?", "What are your features?", "What are you abilities", "can you sing", "can you talk"],
      "responses": ["I am here to solve POS related technical issue", "Right now i'm in developing stage as soon i'm developed"]
    },

    {
      "tag": "POS",
      "patterns": ["Who are you?", "tell me about yourself", "tell me about you", "what is your name"],
      "responses": ["Hi I'm POS Support and i'm an AI created for solving your technical issue", "POS AI here, a very advance chatbot", "POS AI, chatbot of future"],
      "context_set": ""
    },

    {
      "tag": "creator",
      "patterns": ["Who is your creator?", "who created you", "who is your father", "who is your daddy"],
      "responses": ["I was created by POS Team"],
      "context_set": ""
    }, {
      "tag": "issue",
      "patterns": ["Issue", "I have an issue", "Issue occuring frequently", "not working"],
      "responses": ["Can you please say the issue is in pinpad,scale or scanner?"],
      "context_set": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code probably works. I only changed which function was called with the send button and added two empty functions to prevent errors. Take a look at this:

```
from tkinter import *


def radio():
    def sel():
       selection = "You selected the option " + str(var.get())
       label.config(text = selection)


    var = IntVar()
    R1 = Radiobutton(base, text="Option 1", variable=var, value=1,
                      command=sel)
    R1.pack( anchor = W )

    R2 = Radiobutton(base, text="Option 2", variable=var, value=2,
                      command=sel)
    R2.pack( anchor = W )

    R3 = Radiobutton(base, text="Option 3", variable=var, value=3,
                      command=sel)
    R3.pack( anchor = W)

    label = Label(base)
    label.pack() 
    ChatLog.config(state=NORMAL)
    ChatLog.insert(END, "Bot: " + R1 + '\n\n')
    ChatLog.yview(END)

def call():
    pass
def send():
    pass

base = Tk()
base.title("POS Chatbot")
base.geometry("400x500")
base.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
#Create Chat window
ChatLog = Text(base, bd=0, bg="white", height="8", width="50", font="Arial",)
ChatLog.config(state=DISABLED)
ChatLog.config(foreground="#442265", font=("Verdana", 12 ))
#Bind scrollbar to Chat window
scrollbar = Scrollbar(base, command=ChatLog.yview, cursor="heart")
ChatLog['yscrollcommand'] = scrollbar.set
#Create Button to send message
base.bind('<Return>',call ) 
SendButton = Button(base, font=("Verdana",12,'bold'), text="Send", width="12", height=5,
                    bd=0, bg="#32de97", activebackground="#3c9d9b",fg='#ffffff',
                    command= radio )
#Create the box to enter message
EntryBox = Text(base, bd=0, bg="white",width="29", height="5", font="Arial") #Place all components on the screen
scrollbar.place(x=376,y=6, height=386)
ChatLog.place(x=6,y=6, height=386, width=370)
EntryBox.place(x=128, y=401, height=90, width=265)
SendButton.place(x=6, y=401, height=90)
base.mainloop()
```

The problem is likely somewhere else in your code.